# Should javascript files be rendered to adapt server url changing?

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Recently I work on a spring boot project, using Thymeleaf as template engine. Back and front end are separated, ajax is applied to fetch and post data through a set of RESTful service like `/dog/1024`, which is hard coded in javascript. This project is ran under embedded tomcat of spring boot.

Everything works fine, until it is deployed to a tomcat server. In tomcat, this project is deployed under sub-directory-like URL, say `http://host/zoo`, so the RESTful service above should be `/zoo/dog/1024`. URLs in HTML can be rendered by `th:src`, `th:href`, while those in javascript were not rendered, and wrong links in javascript make everything crash. The same issue happened in css files, where background image URL presented.

We have several solution:

---

#### Origin:

My `api.js` file looks like:

```
var Api = {
    Dog: {
        page_url: '/dog/page',
        create_url: '/dog/create',
        update_url: '/dog/update',
        create: function(dog) {
            // post dog entity to create_url
        },
        update: function(dog) {
            // post dog entity to update_url
        }
    },
}
```

So that it can be use in somewhere like `Api.Dog.create(dog)`.

---

#### Solution 0:

Change the URLs manually every time the server URL structure changes.

---

#### Solution 1:

Add a service, say `/resources/api.js`, which generates a javascript file by Thymeleaf, do the same thing to css files.

---

#### Solution 2:

Extract all the URLs to inline javascript/css in HTML fragment, to include the fragment rather than to reference an external file.

---

It seems that solution 1 is cleanest and most friendly to HTTP cache, but is it a good practice to do so?

Or is there any better solution exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No javascript need not know about server urls changing it should be decoupled.

You could use [base tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) to specify sub directories and use relative urls for paths. I am suggesting this as solution 3 to you. The following is extended info of about how we went about doing it in node but maybe you could achieve equivalent of this in spring.

This approach is good if you have something like a pre build step.

Currently in our node project we keep a manifest.json with handles all configs like server path, name, source path of libs etc..,

> {  'path': {
>   'directory': '/zoo',
>   'fallbackpath': '/src'
>   }
>   } // this could also come from a env variable

And we use placeholder for [baseurl](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) in index.html template.

> `<base href=%path.directory% target="_blank">`

And we use gulp [string replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-string-replace) to replace the href when we deploy, reading the config. All our assets and REST calls inside the app will remain relative, no absolute urls.

This way the client side remains free from knowing about deployment changes. This also adds the benefit of keeping the work of dev team not being affected by dev ops work of changing domains etc.

If spring stores the server path as a variable, then maybe you could hook that upto Thymeleaf directly and your work will cut by half.

Comment: Yes, I realize this solution last night as well, and background image URLs in css should be relative paths. The corresponding placeholder in Thymeleaf can be written as `<base th:href="@{/}"></base>`.

Comment: However, the `base` tag has side effects --- when you add an `base` tag in html, e.g. `<base href="/zoo" />`, any `a` tags with `href` goes to `/zoo` instead of current page, since `base` tag "**specify a default URL and a default target for all links on a page**". So, I would rather use custom tag instead.